# Restriction of Tautological Sheaf to a Fiber

Tags: algebraic-geometry, projective-schemes

Let $B$ be a curve (so separated, of finite type, and universally closed $1$-dimensional scheme over a field k) having a closed regular point $b$.

Futhermore let $\mathcal{E}$ be a loacally free sheaf of rank $2$. By consruction of relative Proj with $\mathcal{E}$ we get $S:= Proj(Sym^.\mathcal{E})$ with induced graduation. This provides us the structure morphism $f: S =Proj(Sym^.\mathcal{E}) \to B$.

Obviouly, $S$ has a canonically given taugological sheaf $\mathcal{O}_S(1)$.

Let $f^{-1}(b)$ be the closed fiber with property $f^{-1}(b) \cong \mathbb{P}^1$ as closed subscheme.

My question is why does in this case hold

$$\mathcal{O}_S(1) \vert _{\mathbb{P}^1} = \mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^1}(1)$$

?

Obviously, for arbitrary closed subscheme $C \subset X$ of a scheme $X$ generally never holds 
$$\mathcal{O}_X \vert _C=\mathcal{O}_C$$

or like in our case

$$\mathcal{O}_S (1) \vert _C=\mathcal{O}_C(1)$$

is generally wrong.

But why does here

$$\mathcal{O}_S(1) \vert _{\mathbb{P}^1} = \mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^1}(1)$$

hold? Have I to interpret this "restriction" as a pull back? And does this property (especially conservation of graduation) hold for pull backs?

Comment: Do you see why this is true when $\mathcal{E}$ is free?

Comment: No. I'm quite not sure if it holds if $\mathcal{E}$ is free and if yes, how it can be proved. But I think that if it true then, since the problem is local the statement holds also for locally free sheaves.

Comment: Remark: I already know that if $U$ is a ***open*** subscheme of a scheme $X$ then for structure sheaves one indeed has $\mathcal{O}_X \vert _U=\mathcal{O}_U$, but a structure sheaf of a closed subscheme is locally always given as a quotient...

Comment: You should try and see this when $\mathcal{E}$ is free - if you want also assuming that $B$ is affine - by seeing what $\mathcal{O}(1)$ corresponds to in this case. The general claim would then follow by the fact that $Proj$ is constructed locally.

Comment: Why do you say that $\mathcal{O}_X|_C\neq \mathcal{O}_C$ in general ? In this context, the restriction is not the sheaf theoretic one (given by the functor $i^{-1}$), but the $\mathcal{O}_X$-module one (given by the functor $i^*$).

Comment: Ah ok, sorry, I had just the sheaf theoretic restriction in mind (then it's obviously wrong). So $\mathcal{O}_S (1) \vert _C=\mathcal{O}_C(1)$ holds when $C$ can be relised as a pull back of $S$? And means formally $\mathcal{O}_S (1) \vert _C = i^*\mathcal{O}_S (1)$?